# How does the fb_ref parameter on a Like button actually work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Trying to track sources of Likes to a Facebook Page. Docs from Facebook say:

> ref - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters and can contain 
>   alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). The ref attribute causes 
>   two parameters to be added to the referrer URL when a user clicks a link from a stream story 
>   about a Like action:
>    fb_ref - the ref parameter
>    fb_source - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'other') in which the click
>      occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.

But if you are sending Likes to a Facebook Page - NOT an external website - where can you get this fb_ref data? Appears that it's not available in Insights, and you can't put Google Analytics on a Wall, obviously.

Any insights here?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Remember to upvote answers that are useful to you, including answers to others' questions. "Check" an answer for your questions that best answers your question. In case of ties, go for the earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you would use it as follows:

1. Jim is logged into your site.
2. Put a FB like button on a page on your web site. You're generating the page dynamically so you can generate the FB like button dynamically too. Since "Jim" is logged in, you can include "Jim" as the ref in the FB Like button.
3. Jim, an FB user, LIKES the page, and presses the Like button (that includes the Jim ref).
4. A link to your web page appears on Jim's FB page and all of his friends see it.
5. Susan, a FB friend of Jim, sees the "Like" about your website on Jim's wall (it appears in her newsfeed.) Excited about the link, she presses it.
6. Your website receives an incoming GET request from Susan's browser. It includes the ref=Jim. It also includes the fb_source="profile" This tells your page about the requestor.
7. Your website now displays the page to Susan. The page (dynamically) includes the greeting "Thanks for being a friend of Jim!" etc. Note, you don't know the requestor is Susan, you only know that the requestor found out about the page via Jim's Like of the page.  In order to find out that the person is Susan, you need to get her to signin/signup for your website.

Docs for the extra Get params: see the description of the `ref` param [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

**Added**
Re: `But if you are sending Likes to a Facebook Page - NOT an external website - where can you get this fb_ref data? Appears that it's not available in Insights, and you can't put Google Analytics on a Wall, obviously.`

Do you mean that you're creating a Like button for a page on Facebook that is not a FB app? AFAIK you're right, you can't see the ref data. The ref data is made available to the target of the Like.

You could create a simple website page that re-directs to the FB page. You'd then collect ref info before re-directing to the FB page. Your simple re-direct page would be the target of the Like. But you'd have to fake out FB's graph tags--they'd know that the canonical url for the page was fb.com/xyz. May not be possible to direct to your_site.com/fb/xyz.

Comment: Yes, problem is that we have a Like button for a Facebook Page, NOT an app, and NOT a website (would both be easy because we'd get referrer data.) Yes, I know we can get basic information from Facebook Insights for Like Sources but they are only specific to internal Facebook Like sources (where within Facebook's UI someone Liked your page), not from external sources. Thanks much for your reply. Redirecting won't work either since there's no way to 'Like' programmatically: if we have them Like something then redirect we can't capture the Like anyway...